# Sending 'signed long int' via sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send a long int number using sockets (from client to server).
Both the client and the server are x86 (and identical machines). The client writes 21 long int's to the socket and the server reads it out.

Here is a part of the code.

Server:

```
long int num = 0;
int ret;
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    if ((ret = read(sfd_client, (char *) &num, sizeof(num))) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("number = %d  = %ld  ret = %d\n", i, num, ret);
}
```

Client:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    if (write(sockfd_client, &temp[i], sizeof(long int)) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I noticed that after calling the read the return value is exactly 8, which means that 8 bytes were read; yet the data is always 0. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Also I was looking at various functions, and all cater to unsigned numbers but not signed (ntoh and hton family).

NOTE: Also I noticed that the first read() is 8 bytes, but the following ones are only 1 byte.

Whats the best way I can transmit all these numbers? (Also I noticed that the for loop refuses to quit if I have the read statement in there.)

Solution (The problem was the fact that the read was returning less bytes than required, This function solved it)

```
void read_long(int sockfd_client, char *num) {
    unsigned int size = sizeof(long int);
    int rlen = 0;
    int ret;

    while (rlen < size) {
        if ((ret = read(sockfd_client, (num + rlen), size - rlen)) == -1) {
            perror("read_long");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (ret == 0) {
            perror("socket closed before consumption");
            exit(1);
        }
        rlen += ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing out the numbers before you send them?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually reading properly? On the server, try initializing `num` to something other than 0 and see if this changes the output...

Comment: Yes I am writing the numbers to a file, and it looks fine on the client

Comment: @Brett Yes it always shows up as zero even if I initialize it with something else

Comment: I mean have you literally printed the numbers out immediately before you send them? Or you can try setting them to a specific value immediately before sending: `temp[i] = i;`

Comment: Okay the client has the correct numbers. But I noticed that the first read from socket is correct, the second read and so on are wrong (Since I am getting only 1 byte instead of 8).

Comment: Note that calling read with sizeof(num) returns *up to* sizeof(num) bytes. It might return fewer and it's your responsibility to accumulate them.

Comment: Likewise write() does not guarantee to write the requested number of bytes. You need to check the return value from write to see how many bytes were actually written, and then write the remaining bytes. Probably not happening here, but just saying.

Comment: You were right , should have noticed it earlier. Wrote a function to handle it and it works great :)

Comment: How do you correlate write error(s) (if there is one) - at one endpoint - with read errors - at the other endpoint? Notice that from `socket`'s PoV the data you're sending is just __some data__. Also notice  that you're writing `long`s and reading `char`s, a good point for endianness (or also check [ntoh](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm going to repeat my comment as an answer, given that it turned out to be correct]

Note that calling `read()` with `sizeof(num)` returns **up to** `sizeof(num)` bytes. It might return fewer and it's your responsibility to accumulate them.

Similarly `write()` does not guarantee to write the requested number of bytes. You need to check the return value from write to see how many bytes were actually written, and then write the remaining bytes.

Comment: Note that if your local host is running on an Intel CPU and your remote client is running on, say, SPARC or PowerPC, then you have another problem to deal with — byte order.